# Three missiles are launched, probability that the target is hit?

Tags: probability

I would like to know if I got the correct answer to this problem:

> Missiles $A, B, C$ are launched at a target and their probabilities of hitting are $.9, .8, .5$ respectively. The events of missiles hitting are independent.
>
> a) What is the probability that the target is hit?
>
> b) What is the probability that missile $B$ hit the target, given that the target is hit?

**My Solution:**

a)  Let $A, B, C$ be the events that the target was hit by missiles $A, B, C$ respectively. We want to find $P(A \cup B \cup C) = P[(A' \cap B' \cap C')'] = 1 - P(A' \cap B' \cap C') = 1 - (1-.9)(1-.8)(1-.5) = .99$

b) Let $H = A \cup B \cup C$. We want to find $P(B|H) = \dfrac {P(B \cap H)}{P(H)} = \dfrac {P(B) \cdot P(H|B)}{P(H)} = \dfrac {(.8)(1)}{.99} \approx .80808$

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: it is very much correct so

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks, I was a little eeked out when I got a probability of 1 in my calculation. In retrospect I guess I shouldve figured that B intersection H is just B

Comment: Yes, that is true :) The method you followed is just a more general method I guess, which will work every time - this was just a case where that one step could have been skipped